# Kafka replication Mirror maker

Tags: apache-kafka, disaster-recovery

I have a question regarding DR for kafka.
I have set up my PROD - DR kafka, I need to sync my PROD (topics, messages ) with DR. What is the approach I can follow here. Below are my questions assuming Mirror maker is in place. We are using hortonworks HDP 2.5.5

1. Each time when I create a new topic in Prod do I need to create the same topic in DR as well?
2. Do i need to have mirrir maker running on DR as well?

Comment: Consider using Confluent Replicator in place of MM as it will create topics, sync metadata changes, filter and transform messages, and replicate messages between multiple sites while preserving their original timestamps for proper offsetsForTimes() offset lookup upon failover.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. I cannot use confluent, we have support from HTWX and it is not recommended, if any support is needed they will not provide.

Comment: Note replicator is a commercial product, the open source alternative is mirrormaker 2 which is included with kafka